# Find the circle on the experimental image (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a series of the experimental images. In order to process it, at first, I need to determine the area of interest. This area is between two concentric circles. These circles can be a little different on each image (e.g. center can be shifted by a small distance).

In order to find these circles, I converted my image to binary image. Now it looks like this:
[image]

I am interested in the biggest circle and the one after the biggest (See note on the picture). Does anyone know a fast algorithm that can find it? Exhausted search seems to be a bad option. I know, that at each image the locations and radii of these circles can change only by a little. Here is a link to .mat file with the picture I attached [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_0SH1ttXgtddnV1M0RobGhYSVU/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks,

Comment: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html might interest you

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. Trying to implement it

Comment: It's actually working. The only thing is I want to find the "inner radius", not the outer one (my circles have finite width). But I think I can solve this issue by myself.

Comment: @MikhailGenkin Please consider creating an answer yourself. It may be useful for others with a similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this task even without using inbuilt function *imfindcircles*. I follow the following method. Get all the non-zero pixels using *find*. Now you have all the points, I want to classify them into different circles, for this I will use *histogram*. I can fix the number of bins (which is number of circles) here. Once I got all the points separated, I have scattered points along a circle..with these points, I will fit a circle along those points. You may check the below code:

```
load Sample.mat ;
I = Immm ;
[y,x] = find(I) ;
%% Get Bounding box
x0 = min(x) ; x1 = max(x) ;
y0 = min(y) ; y1 = max(y) ;
% length and breadth 
L = abs(x1-x0) ;
B = abs(y1-y0) ;
% center bounding box
C = [x0+B/2 y0+L/2] ;
%% Get distances of the points from center of bounding box
data = repmat(C,[length(x),1])-[x,y] ;
dist = sqrt(data(:,1).^2+data(:,2).^2);
%% Classify the points into circles 
nbins = 4 ;   % number of circles you want
[N,edges,bin] = histcounts(dist,nbins) ;
% plot the classified circle points for check 
figure(1)
imshow(I)
hold on
for i = 1:nbins
    plot((x(bin==i)),y(bin==i),'.','color',rand(1,3)) ;
end

%% Circle's radii and center 
Circ = cell(nbins,1) ;
for i = 1:nbins 
    [xc1,yc1,R] = circfit(x(bin==i),y(bin==i)) ;
    Circ{i} = [xc1 yc1 R] ;
end
figure(2)
imshow(I)
hold on
th = linspace(0,2*pi) ;
for i = 1:nbins
    xc = Circ{i}(1)+Circ{i}(3)*cos(th) ;
    yc = Circ{i}(2)+Circ{i}(3)*sin(th) ;
    plot(xc,yc,'color',rand(1,3),'linewidth',3) ;
end
```

Circ is cell, which centers and Radii of circles. You can download the function *circfit* from this link: http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_fit_a_circle_to_a_set_of_XY_data.3F
[image]

Comment: This is a good approach, but the center of the circle is not necessary exactly in the center (although close)